# Ejecución de Python con Streamlit

Tags: python

Estoy desarrollando una rutina en Python para luego utilizar *Streamlit* y ejecutarla en un navegador. Sin embargo, me enfrento a un problema que no entiendo: la ejecución del código Python en *Streamlit* parece seguir un comportamiento diferente a lo esperado. Veamos este ejemplo:

```
import streamlit as st

def factorial(n):
   if n<=1:
        return 1
else:
    fact = 1
    for k in range(2,n+1):
        fact *= k
    return fact
    
st.write("Factorial defined...")

# main
counter=0
n = 0
while (n!=-1):
    user_input = st.text_input("Nº to calculate factorial, type -1 to end:", "0", key = str(counter))
    counter += 1
    n = int(user_input)
    if (n != -1):
        st.write(factorial(n))
    else:
        st.write('End')
```

El código Python se ejecuta de manera extraña: no se detiene en la solicitud de entrada de datos para luego continuar, sino que continúa. El "widget" para introducir datos es recreado cada vez por lo que es necesario un contador para que se le asigne a cada "widget" un código diferente. Finalmente, el código aquí arriba entra en un ciclo infinito.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Este comportamiento se debe a que la función st.text_input() retorna el valor de la entrada del usuario, pero no detiene la ejecución del código. Por lo tanto, el ciclo while sigue ejecutándose sin esperar a que el usuario ingrese algún valor.

Para solucionar este problema, puedes usar la función st.button() junto con la función st.cache() para crear un botón que el usuario pueda presionar para ejecutar la lógica de cálculo del factorial. La función st.cache() se utiliza para "memorizar" el resultado del cálculo del factorial, de manera que si el usuario ingresa el mismo número varias veces, el cálculo se realiza solo una vez.

A continuación te muestro un ejemplo de cómo podrías implementar esta solución:

```
import streamlit as st

@st.cache
def factorial(n):
   if n<=1:
        return 1
else:
    fact = 1
    for k in range(2,n+1):
        fact *= k
    return fact

# main
counter = 0
while True:
    user_input = st.text_input("Nº to calculate factorial, type -1 to end:", "0", key = str(counter))
    counter += 1
    n = int(user_input)
    if (n == -1):
        st.write('End')
        break
    else:
        if st.button("Calculate"):
            st.write(factorial(n))
```

En este caso, se crea un botón llamado "Calculate" que el usuario debe presionar para que se calcule el factorial del número ingresado. La ejecución del código se detiene en la función st.button() hasta que el usuario presiona el botón, y luego continúa calculando y mostrando el resultado del factorial.